# How to add a 2nd account to receive imessages

Tags: ipad

My wife and I just bought an iPad and I set it up using my iCloud account info.  Is it possible to have her receive text messages also.

Comment: No, the iPad is designed as a one-user device, not as a one-family device. Each user has to have their own iPad, not their own account on a shared iPad.

Comment: ahhh… I missed that  - one iPad 2 accounts… no, not going to work well. I'd mis-read 2 iPads, one account.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible.

Go to *Settings* > *Messages* > *Sending and Receiving* > *Add e-mail address*

This works for FaceTime as well:

Go to *Settings* > *FaceTime* > *Add e-mail address*

However, as Mike and Tetsujin stated above, it is not possible to use multiple iCloud/Apple ID accounts on the iPad ;).